# Binary requires older version of a shared object

Tags: shared-library

I was given a binary to execute, but running `ldd ./name_of_binary` gives

```
libABC.so.1 => not found
```

(I replaced the library name with 'libABC' because I'd like a general answer)

I have `libABC.so.2`.  How can I get `libABC.so.1`?  Or would the answer be specific for each library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a pinch you could try to just create a symlink.

```
ln -s -T /lib/libABC.so.2 ~/libs/libABC.so.1
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/libs/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

This is bad because the API will probably be different, but it may work temporarily (but it will eventually crash or give unpredictable behavior, it might also be a security issue).

The better option would be to find a copy of libABC.so.1 (try http://packages.ubuntu.com/). You could download the old package, install it into a nonstandard directory (like /opt/ or ~/libs/):

```
dpkg -i --instdir=/opt/ ABC-1.deb
```

then add that path to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/lib/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Its possible that just installing into root will work (in which case you can do this), but there will probably be a conflict with the newer version. And may cause issues.

```
sudo dpkg -i ABC-1.deb
```

Comment: Thanks, I followed the second method and it worked.  I went to the [link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) you provided and searched for libABC1.  I downloaded it (even though it was for Ubuntu 13.10 and I'm on 14.04) and installed it to `/opt/lib` although it ended up at `/opt/lib/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`, which I added to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.